# Calendar Validation in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

how can i forbid past date to be chosen in my calendar?

this is my asp code:

```
<td>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`DayRender` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender.aspx) of the [`Calendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar.aspx) control.

.aspx:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" SelectionMode="None"     
     OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" 
</asp:Calendar>
```

And your event in code behind::

```
Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(sender As Object, e As DayRenderEventArgs) Handles Calendar1.DayRender
    If e.Day.Date < Date.Today Then
        e.Day.IsSelectable = False
        e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray
    End If
End Sub
```